# RxJava, execute observable only if first was empty

Tags: java, rx-java

I want to insert a new user into my database only if a user with the same email does not exist.

Therefor I have two Observables:
The first one emits a user with a specific email or completes without emitting anything.
The second Observable inserts a new user and returns an Object of this newly created user.

My problem is, that I don't want the user emmitted by the first Observable (if existent) is transported to the Subscriber. Rather I would like to map it to null).

```
Observable<UserViewModel> observable = 
    checkAndReturnExistingUserObservable
        .map(existingUser -> null)
        .firstOrDefault(
            insertAndReturnNewUserObservable
                .map(insertedUser -> mMapper.map(insertedUser)
        )
```

This was the last thing I tried, but it says "cyclic inference" at the second map operator.

To summarize. I want to perform a second Observable only if the first completed empty but if not I don't want to return the Data emmitted by first rather I want to return null.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I have an anwser about the operator to use to correctly emits your objects. However, I am not really sure about the cyclic inference. Can you post code of `insertAndReturnNewUserObservable` and the `mMapper.map(...)`  just to be sure. Also, IMHO, returning null is a pretty bad idea. But I will give details in my answer after seeing your code ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is the `switchIfEmpty` operator for this kind of operation:

```
checkAndReturnExistingUserObservable
.switchIfEmpty(insertAndReturnNewUserObservable)
```

**Edit**

If you don't need an existing user, there was a flatMap-based answer that turned the first check into a boolean value and dispatched based on its value:

```
checkAndReturnExistingUserObservable
.map(v -> true).firstOrDefault(false)
.flatMap(exists -> exists ? Observable.empty() : insertAndReturnNewUserObservable);
```

Comment: he also wants to emit a null value if empty, but I think switchIfEmpty is the best solution !

Comment: I'm not sure why the OP wants null if the user exists but you can map it in before the switchIfEmpty if necessary. The OP can also use a dummy user object instead of null or a new flag in the user object itself. Otherwise, there was a flatMap-based answer (now deleted).

Comment: The problem with this approach is, that it will also return the found User of the first Observable (What I don't want).

Currently I'm trying the flat map answer which seems to solve my problem in a clean way. Unfortunately it is deleted so I can't accept it as correct.